# Disable effect adjustPan in EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

The adjustPan helps a lot by raising the content present in the ScrollView, I'm making a chat app and I want the messages to go up and the edittext to stay on top of the keyboard, but when I move the cursor through the EditText the entire layout goes down and the cursor is always stuck with the keyboard, I want to make the cursor move freely through the EditText without scrolling down the entire layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/above"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mensagens"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/papel"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/papel"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mensagem"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/icon_dimen_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/comandos"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <EditText
                      
                    android:id="@+id/textoMensagem"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/campo_mensagem"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:hint="Mensagem..."
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|bottom"
                    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:isScrollContainer="false"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/enviarMensagem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_dimen_enviar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="13dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrJHn.jpg)